# I would like to store new data from a form tag into a php file?

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to make a PHP page which will ask a the user for three things. An email, a first name, and a last name. I want this data to be stored and saved on my computer. Right now I am running XAMPP locally.

When I input the form tags it redirects. I would like to save the data.

Let's say that the user (myself) put a name like "John Mayer" with an email of "johnmayer@gmail.com" how would I save that information on a PHP page after the sumbit button is hit?

Comment: share your code that u used

Comment: what do you means save in computer? you can save in session or cookies..

Comment: I haven't written any code to it. i ran an example but the example I found online did not work. I had a blank page. I'm not sure what to do to get the desired result.

Comment: I would like to save the input to a file on the computer not in session coolkies.

Answer (score 0):

Your data input page containing the HTML Form should look something like this:

```
<form action="save-data.php" method="POST">
    <input name="firstname" type="text" />
    <input name="lastname" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

---

now in the PHP file named save-data.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
    $data = $_POST['firstname'] . '-' . $_POST['lastname'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('/tmp/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

Note that 'tmp/mydata.txt' is the path to the file you want to write your data. And it must have the proper write permissions.

Comment: Okay well first off thank you for taking time on this special occasion of the new year to help me out, Happy New Years! Anywho, I ran your code as posted and I got this error message from Chrome


Notice: Undefined index: savedata in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP example form\testSave.php on line 24

Comment: line 24:    $savedata = $_REQUEST['savedata'];

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form action="mailer.php?savedata=1" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
    LastName: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
    Your Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $savedata = $_REQUEST['savedata'];
    if ($savedata == 1){ 
       $data = $_POST['first_name'];
       $data .= $_POST['last_name'];
       $data .= $_POST['email'];
       $file = "YOURDATAFILE.txt"; 

       $fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
       fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

       fclose($fp); 
       echo "Your Form has been Submitted!";

   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys. I figured this out after writing some code myself.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>HTML</title>
        <meta name="author" content="nelly" />
        <!-- Date: 2016-01-01 -->
    </head>
    <body>
<?php

echo 'Hello' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["first_name"]);

    $input = $_POST["first_name"];
    $handle = fopen("savingData.txt" , "a+");
    $fileName = 'savingData.txt';
    $data = $handle;
    if (is_writable($fileName))
    {
        if (!$handle = fopen($fileName, 'a+'))
        {
            echo "Cannot open file ($fileName)";
            exit; 
        }

        if (fwrite($handle, $input ) === FALSE)
        {
            echo "Cannot write to file name";
            exit;
        }

        echo "Success wrote ($input) to file ($fileName)";

        fclose($handle);
    }

    echo "the file name is not writable?"


?>
    </body>
</html>
```